# Laravel insert using query builder

Tags: laravel, insert

I have second database in Laravel.
I want to insert data to second database and I search topic where as an example is given:

```
$users = DB::connection('mysql2')->select(...);
```

How can I insert in the same way?

Answer (score 1):

Pass an array of fields and values to the insert function like so:

```
DB::connection('mysql2')->table('your_table')->insert(
    ['email' => 'john@example.com', 'name' => 'John Smith']
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The insert method accepts an array of column names and values:

```
DB::table('mysql2')->insert(
['email' => 'john@example.com', 'votes' => 0]
);
```

Don't forget to use 'use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;' at the beginning